# how to remove white space in justified css

Tags: html, css, whitespace

If I am using 
`text-align:justify`
  paragraph shows unwanted space between words to maintain specified width. Searched in internet but didn't get any proper result. I used **white-space** also but no use
 
fiddle :[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sebin/eEDXL/10/)

Comment: So what do you expect when you use `justify`?

Comment: a combination of text-align left + justify

Comment: It it is left than it's not justified anymore :) also, I liked Mr_Green's solution

Comment: The hyphens property `hyphens: auto;` in addition of `text-align: justify;` can reduce (and not remove) the white spaces. Also, you have to specify the `lang` attribute for hyphens to work, and only the english has really a decent support on all browsers. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/hyphens

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The closest solution would be using `word-break: break-all` but this will also break words. If you are ok with this then go with this solution:

```
.sample_test p{
    word-break: break-all;
}
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/eEDXL/12/)

**Edit (Nov, 2021)**

Other closest better solution is using [`hyphens: auto`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/hyphens). We have to mention the global attribute `lang` to the HTML element to make this work:

```css
.sample_test {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 400px;
  height: auto;
}

.sample_test p {
  /* word-break: break-all; */
  hyphens: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="sample_test" lang="en">
  <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it.</p>
  <p>Contrary to popular belief,.. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC,</p>
  <p>There are many variations of passages of Lorem Ipsum available, but the majority have suffered alteration in some form, by injected humour, or randomised words which don't look even slightly believable. If you are going to use a passage of Lorem Ipsum,
    you need to be sure there isn't anything embarrassing hidden in the middle of text. All the Lorem Ipsum generators on the Internet tend to repeat predefined chunks as necessary, making this the first true generator on the Internet. It uses a dictionary
    of over 200 Latin words,</p>
</div>
```

Comment: The cure is much worse than the disease.

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela "The best Medicines are always bitter".. you should check the above comment. can you please explain what is wrong with it?

Comment: It is ab surd to d eal wit h a typ ographi cal issue in a m anner th at c auses wo rds to be ar bitraril y broke n.

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela your point is correct, I even mention the same in my post. but still the OP is happy with my answer.. It means he is ok with word breaking.

Comment: Being happy with it does not mean it is OK, and you did not mention that the “solution” is absurd.

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela not sure why you think this solution is absurd. `word-break: break-all` does break the words which is a known fact. and I notified OP saying `If you are ok with this then go with this solution`. I am not saying you to give my points back but I just want to know exactly what is wrong with this solution apart from word breaking?

Answer (score 2):

When you are using `text-align: justify`, you are *asking* browsers to add spacing, and browsers implement this as added spacing between words. According to CSS Text Module Level 3 LC, you could additionally use [`text-justify: distribute`](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-text/#text-justify) to ask browsers to use added spacing both between words and between characters in words, to achieve a more balanced result, but it is debatable whether the results are really better, and this feature has been implemented only in IE (long ago).

What you can do to improve the situation is to use **hyphenation.** This generally reduces the need for added spacing, though of course it cannot remove it. The most effective way is to use [Hyphenator.js](https://code.google.com/p/hyphenator/), which means that you need to declare the language of your page, e.g. `<html lang=en>`, to set the `hyphenate` class on any elements where text should be hyphenated, e.g. with `<body class=hyphenate>` to hyphenate everything, and to just add the code

```
<script src=http://hyphenator.googlecode.com/svn/tags/Version%204.2.0/Hyphenator.js></script>
<script>Hyphenator.run();</script>
```